# Inconsistent return types of linq queries with orderby clauses

Tags: c#, linq

Does anyone know why the types of the result of these two queries is different?

```cs
// q1 is IOrderedEnumerable<int>
var q1 = from c1 in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
         orderby c1
         select c1;

// q2 is IEnumerable<int>
var q2 = from c1 in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
         from c2 in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
         where c1 == c2
         orderby c1
         select c1;
```

I cannot work out why q2 is not *also* an `IOrderedEnumerable<int>`.

Using a 'join' clause doesn't make a difference:

```
// q3 is IEnumerable<int>
var q3 = from c1 in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
         join c2 in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
         on c1 equals c2
         orderby c1
         select c1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the very first query there is no actual `Select` operating being performed.  The `select` is selecting the current item in the sequence, which is a no op, so the `Select` call is simply omitted.   With the `Select` call omitted, the `OrderBy` is the last call in the query, and it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

For the second (and third) queries, the `select` is actually selecting out something meaningful, and can't be omitted.  (In the second query the `SelectMany` is going to return an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type, as does the `Join` in the third query.)  So in these cases the `Select` is still there in the query, and `Select` returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

It's easy enough when you look at what the queries are translated to, which will be the moral equivalent of the following:

```
var q1a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.OrderBy(c1 => c1);

var q2a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.SelectMany(c1 => new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(c2 => new { c1, c2 }))
    .Where(variables => variables.c1 == variables.c2)
    .OrderBy(variables => variables.c1)
    .Select(variables => variables.c1);

var q3a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Join(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, c1 => c1, c2 => c2, (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })
    .OrderBy(variables => variables.c1)
    .Select(variables => variables.c1);
```

Given that these are what your queries are equivalent to, it should be clear why only the first one returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Can you clarify how that's a SelectMany in q2?

Comment: Nice explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Now the actual types returned (rather that the declared interfaces) are:

q1: `OrderedEnumerable<int, int>`

q2: `Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<AnonymousType<int, int>, int>`

(q3 same as q2)

Comment: The question is specifying the *compile time* types of the variables, and does so correctly.  You also aren't answering the question of why the types are different.

Comment: This does not answer question about 'why' they are different